# Arellano cluster-robust standard errors with households fixed effects: what about the village level?

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

Consider the following regression line:

$y_{i,t}=b_0+b_1X_{t,g}+a_{i}+e_{i,t}$

where $y_{i,t,g}$ is the consumption of household $i=1,..,N$, at time $t=1,...,T$, $X_{t,g}$ is a weather index measured at the village level, i.e. it varies between villages $g=1,...,G$ and time periods but not within villages, $a_{i}$ is a household fixed effect constant over time and $e_{i,t}$ is an error term.

I estimate the above regression with a within estimator thanks to the R Cran package -plm- and, as suggested [here](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcameron.econ.ucdavis.edu%2Fresearch%2FCameron_Miller_Cluster_Robust_October152013.pdf&ei=qt9AVfiHCMP4UKrugMgC&usg=AFQjCNH5WQ2FttIg1VlhJ9LCIZ0EzG9Opg&sig2=fDrHxZRBQInV1lAhBaLIgg&bvm=bv.91665533,d.d24) and [here](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fplm%2Fvignettes%2Fplm.pdf&ei=5N9AVeyBBoTxUp_RgOAK&usg=AFQjCNEcvKAZyrIdvrBzXdegjTYbNVXRZw&sig2=f-B9rdIQDWew5O1L3NhBaA&bvm=bv.91665533,d.d24), I compute Arellano (1987) cluster and heteroskedastic robust standard errors allowing for clusterization at the household level.

Another source of heteroskedasticity is the error in the measurement of the weather index $X_{t,g}$. This will cause the errors to be clustered at the village level, right?

Will the household fixed effects $a_i$ and the use of the Arellano standard error solve the issue of clustered measurement errors at the village level?

Or, if it is not the case, should I for instance inflate $V_A(\hat{b})$ with $D$:

$V_A'(\hat{b})=DV_A(\hat{b})$

where the Arellano variance $V_A$ is:

$V_A(\hat{b})=(X_i^TX_i)^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N X_i^Te_ie_i^TX_i(X_i^TX_i)$

and the formula for the degree of freedom adjustment, $D$, meant to  take care of clustering (and found [here](http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.ch/2014/10/easy-clustered-standard-errors-in-r.html) and [here](http://www.richard-bluhm.com/clustered-ses-in-r-and-stata-2/)) is:

$D=\frac{G}{G-1}\frac{N-1}{N-K}$

where $K$ is the model rank and $G$ and $N$ are respectively the number of clusters and the sample size.

Comment: If your $X_{t,g}$ is measured with error, wouldn't $b_1$ be biased no matter how hard you try to correct for clustering? if you have enough villages, there will probably be no harm in clustering at the village level. Alternatively, if you know more about the measurement properties of $X_{t,g}$, you could entertain random effects multilevel modeling that all psychologists use for all of their clustered data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, random multilevel modeling sounds quite scarry to me. The measurement error is likely to be random so that it shouldn't bias the result, but only increase the variance, right? Actually, even discarding the measurement error, there will be some clustering at the village level given the fact that the weather index value is the same within each village. Would the Arellano standard error and the households fixed effects do the trick in such setting or should I inflate the standard error further?

Comment: When regressors are measured with error, coefficients are shrunk towards zero, which is often referred to as "measurement error attenuation bias" -- I thought most econometric classes cover that way before the clustered standard errors. Also, I don't know why you are calling them Arellano standard errors; there were people before him who did similar work, so you can as well call them Huber-Fuller-Binder clustered standard errors. If the data came from a survey that had villages as primarily sampling units, you have to cluster at village level no matter what by design.

Comment: Well, if the measurement error is uncorrelated with X (it is what I meant by random), it only increases the variance of $b$. The measurement attenuation bias comes in if there is a positive correlation between X and the measurement error, right? I didn't know about Huber-Fuller-Binder clustered standard error, I am using the terminology I found in the panel econometric field. Thanks for the insight on sampling.